# Convert Array to string from special index

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms

I have a simple question.

I have an string array of length 5 and want to convert it to a string. But I am interested in to convert ***from a specified index(for example from `Array_temp[2]` ) till end of array***.

I know the following code will do it for whole array not part of it. Could please one help me how can I do it?

```
string.Join("/", Array_temp)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Skip` method of `Linq`:

```
string.Join("/", Array_temp.Skip(2));
```

`Skip` will return an `IEnumerable` of whatever you called it on and skip the first `x` (`2` in this example) entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload of [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that lets you specify an offset and a count:

```
string[] Array_temp = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
int offset = 2;
var result = string.Join("/", Array_temp, offset, Array_temp.Length - offset);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 3/4/5
```

Note that this is somewhat faster than the version that accepts an `IEnumerable<string>` because it has some optimisations arising from the fact that it knows in advance how many strings there are.